# Macro in LibreOffice to change the background of an Impress Slide to a solid black color

Tags: vba, libreoffice, libreoffice-impress

Looked all around and could not find it. Need a macro so that I can repeat it 695 times, on 695 different files I have.  Documentation is kind of uneasy, or I am unlucky.

I could do it in Microsoft VBA as follows:

```
Sub VbaBlackies
    Dim oSl As Slide
    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        With oSl
            .FollowMasterBackground = msoFalse
            .DisplayMasterShapes = msoFalse
            With .background
                .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                .Fill.BackColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End With
            End With
        Next oSl
End Sub
```

I am looking for something similar in LibreOffice BASIC. I could get started in the code this way:

```
Sub Main
Dim oDoc As Object
Dim oDPages As Object
Dim oDPage As Object
oDoc= ThisComponent
oDPages = oDoc.getDrawPAges()
For i=0 To oDPages.count()-1
    oDPage = oDPages.getByIndex(i)
    oDPage.Background = RGB(0,0,0)  'This does not work.
    'I have no idea on how to access the object's properties and alter them.
    Next i
End Sub
```

Any ideas, please?

Comment: record a macro of the change being done manually. that may give you the code that you need.

Comment: Tried that, but Impress does not record macros.

Comment: Recorded a macro performing similar operation in Calc, changing the background color of a cell. Got me some tips, but have trouble getting to a "Frame" reference of a Slide object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is in Listing 15.1 of [Andrew Pitonyak's macro document](http://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php), an essential reference for macro programming.

```vb
Sub ChangeBackground
    Dim oDoc as Object
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    Dim oDrawPages as Object, oDrawPage as Object
    oDrawPages = oDoc.getDrawPages()
    oDrawPage = oDrawPages.getByIndex(0)
    Dim oBackground as Object
    oBackground = oDoc.createInstance("com.sun.star.drawing.Background")
    oBackground.FillColor = RGB(250,0,0)
    oDrawPage.Background = oBackground
End Sub
```

API documentation is at https://www.openoffice.org/api/docs/common/ref/com/sun/star/drawing/Background.html.

Answer (score 1):

YES! Worked like a charm, thanks a lot for the answers!

This is the final code that worked out for me:

```
Sub Main
Dim oDoc As Object
Dim oDPages As Object
Dim oDPage As Object

oDoc = ThisComponent
oDPages = oDoc.getDrawPAges()

For i=0 To oDPages.count()-1
    oDPage = oDPages.getByIndex(i)
    Dim oBackground As Object
    oBackground = oDoc.createInstance("com.sun.star.drawing.Background")
    oBackground.FillColor = RGB(0,0,0)
    oDPage.Background = oBackground
    Next i
End Sub
```